# Google Calendar api missing DateTime

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

i'm triing to develop an apk which use google calendar api in Eclipse.
my problem is i'm stuck with the DateTime format.
i'm added the jar file to build path but still missing the DateTime.

Can you help me?
Thank you!

the jars:

```
google-api-client-1.20.0
google-http-client-gson-1.20.0
google-api-services-calendar-v3-rev125-1.20.0
google-api-services-calendar-v3-rev132-1.20.0
```

Comment: Did you include com.google.api.client.util.DateTime? check this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android

Comment: yes, i have added these 3 *.jar-s.
google-api-services-calendar-v3-rev132-1.20.0.jar
google-api-client-1.20.0.jar
google-http-client-gson-1.20.0